# Count from a count (distinct)

Tags: mysql, count

I have a query like this:

```
select * from questions as q  
    left join question_filters as qf on q.id = qf.question_id 
    left join users as u on q.user_id = u.id 
    left join trainers as t on q.trainer_id = t.id 
where q.deleted_at is null  
    and qf.filter_id in (3,4) 
    and q.status = 'published' 
    and q.published_at < now() 
    group by q.id
having count(distinct qf.filter_id) = 2
```

I have an "**ALL IN**" case, and I found this links works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505045/mysql-in-operator-must-match-all-values.

But now I want to make a **count** for that same query:
My problem:
This query gaves me the error "Duplicate column name "ID" (all the tables in the join have ID)

```
select count(*) from ((select * from questions as q  
    left join question_filters as qf on q.id = qf.question_id 
    left join users as u on q.user_id = u.id 
    left join trainers as t on q.trainer_id = t.id 
where q.deleted_at is null  
    and qf.filter_id in (3,4) 
    and q.status = 'published' 
    and q.published_at < now() 
    group by q.id
having count(distinct qf.filter_id) = 2)) as first_query
```

Another attempt:

```
select count(q.id) from questions as q  
    left join question_filters as qf on q.id = qf.question_id 
    left join users as u on q.user_id = u.id 
    left join trainers as t on q.trainer_id = t.id 
where q.deleted_at is null  
    and qf.filter_id in (3) 
    and q.status = 'published' 
    and q.published_at < now() 
    group by q.id
having count(distinct qf.filter_id) = 1
```

returns many results, one for each result.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query has a `group by q.id`. While MySQL allows you to use `select *` in a group by query, it is not the best practice, unless you are 100% sure that you want the undesired side effects. If you wan to not have ill-determined results, you should only include in the `select` list columns are are **functionally dependent** on the group by columns/expressions.

In your case, that would be any column from `questions`, `users` or `trainers` because you group by the primary key of `questions` and the joins to the other 2 tables are based `on` foreign key relationship from `questions`. But you should not put any column from the `question_filters` because that join is on a reverse foreign key relationship.

If/when you move to version 5.7, you would get an error with the 1st query otherwise.

Also, the `left` join to `question_filters` is actually treated as `inner` join, due to the `where` condition (`and qf.filter_id in (3,4)`). You could also change that to be explicit. The query becomes:

```
select q.*, u.*, t.* 
from questions as q  
    join question_filters as qf on q.id = qf.question_id 
    left join users as u on q.user_id = u.id 
    left join trainers as t on q.trainer_id = t.id 
where q.deleted_at is null  
    and qf.filter_id in (3,4) 
    and q.status = 'published' 
    and q.published_at < now() 
    group by q.id
having count(distinct qf.filter_id) = 2 ;
```

---

Now for error you got with the `count` query: this is caused by the multiple columns with identical alias (`id`) in the subquery's `select` list. You can easily solve that by using `select 1` or `select q.*` (or just `select null`).

What's more, the joins to  `users` and `trainers` are redundant for that query (because they are `left` joins) and so can be removed. The query becomes:

```
select count(*) 
from 
   (select 1 from questions as q  
        join question_filters as qf on q.id = qf.question_id 
    where q.deleted_at is null  
        and qf.filter_id in (3,4) 
        and q.status = 'published' 
        and q.published_at < now() 
        group by q.id
    having count(distinct qf.filter_id) = 2
   ) as first_query ;
```

Comment: Really, REALLY good info! Sorry for the extra left joins, the full query has more conditions, involving those tables.  "select 1" worked great!!